# Ternary Operator im trying to get the scanner results of what user entered but its not going how i thought

Tags: java, operators, java.util.scanner

not understanding why its not reading correctly

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ternary_operator {     
            
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\r?\n");               
        
        int i = 100;
        int j = 200;
        String light;
        String heavy;
        light = (" You are light");
        heavy= ("You are heavy");
        System.out.println("How much do you weigh? 100 or 200 ?"); 
        
        s = s.nextInt();
         
        s =  i==i?light:heavy;
         
        System.out.println(s);      
    }    
}
```

Comment: could you please provide us with one example in which this: i==i is not going to return true? Also: how do you expect this: s = s.nextInt(); to compile?

Comment: Not reading correctly, it doesn't even compile.

Comment: also, you should re-look your logic. Somebody who weighs would be "light", but somebody who weighs only 90 would be "heavy"

Comment: `int weight = s.nextInt(); System.out.println(weight == i ? light : weight == j ? heavy : "Can't " + "really say for sure! You didn't provide one of the requested weights!");`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use `s` as a `Scanner`, an `int`, and a `String`.

This is the section that needs tweaking:

```java
s = s.nextInt();
s = i==i?light:heavy;
```

Also `i==i` doesn't make a lot of sense. It is always going to be true. I'm going to guess you meant `(whatever variable s.nextInt() will be assigned to)==i`

Comment: considering the code, could you give one scenario in which i==100 will not return true?

Comment: Yeah. i know thats the section ive tried tweaking it numerous times... im trying to learn Ternary Operator but im not getting it... i guess ill try and tweak (not meth) some more ...hahaha!!  thank you...?

Comment: thats what the colon is for " : " or else statement

Comment: Well, the ternary operator (besides the comparison you have initially) isn't really the problem. It's that the code won't actually compile as is because you're using ```s``` as multiple types of variables.

Comment: well, i have no idea...i been trying to get this and i cant see what im doing wrong. I know its not right or i wouldnt be.

Answer (score 0):

```java
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\r?\n");
System.out.println("How much do you weigh? 100 or 200 ?");
int a = s.nextInt();

String light;
String heavy;
light = (" You are light");
heavy = ("You are heavy");

String result = (a == 100) ? light : (a == 200) ? heavy : "not correct answer";

System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Uhm I think that s, a, light, heavy and result could be final. Then I don't understand why you separate the variable declaration to initialization. It is better to write something like that: `final String light = "You are light"`.